# Disable backlight device

Tags: kernel-modules, backlight

I have two backlight devices in /sys/class/backlight: toshiba and intel_backlight. The former works only before I put my laptop on sleep and the latter works perfectly.

`/sys/class/backlight/toshiba/type` = "platform" while `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/type` = "raw".

Gnome 3.16 is somehow using the former even though I have the following `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` file:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "card0"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
    BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

I'm trying to find a workaround (I already posted a bug report). Is it possible to eliminate the `toshiba` device altogether without breaking acpi or other functionality?

I'm using Arch linux with latest kernel (4.0.1) but the problem is present even with the lts kernel (3.14).

Comment: A starting point could be the different workarounds proposed by ubuntu [kernel backlight debugging](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight) page. Tested some once for a similar problem, but finding the right fix is tough.

Comment: I consulted that site and I know what works but Gnome doesn't seem to know the same and therefore I'm trying to remove that choice by leaving just one backlight device.

Comment: That's what the kernel boot options in the "Disabling the ACPI backlight driver" section are intended for. Do you still have two entries when setting these boot parameters ?

Comment: Yes, If I remove the `acpi_backlight=vendor` parameter I get a third device acpi_video0 linked to toshiba (same values).